# Convert json database column to object automatically

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I want laravel to convert my json database column value into an object automatically when it is retrieved.

The column migration code is `$table->json('data');`.

An example of the value in this column is `{"last_name": "Blow", "first_name": "Joe"}`. I've used `json_encode()` on an array upon insertion.

I've tried casting on the model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'data' => 'json',
];
```

As well as an accessor:

```
public function getDataAttribute($value) {
  return json_decode($value);
}
```

Neither of which seem to work.

How do I do this properly?

Comment: What is the output? Are there any errors? Can you dd() the result of an example call please?

Comment: `dd()` outputs `"data" => "{"last_name": "Blow", "first_name": "Joe"}"` in the `#attributes` array.

Comment: Okay. Can you try ->toArray() on that instance please?

Comment: An you want array output ?

Comment: what does `dd($model->data)` output?

Comment: I don't want an array, I want an object...

Comment: `dd($model->data)` outputs `"{"last_name": "Blow", "first_name": "Joe"}"`. It is still retrieving it as a string and not an object or array.

Comment: What you're doing is the correct way to do this, what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @kjdion84 I just wanted to see what that was outputting, if the toArray() method was correctly processing the JSON.

Comment: OK it just started magically working. Must have been a cache thing. Thanks and sorry everyone.

Comment: Congrats anyway

Comment: Its working perfectly with the accessor now :)

Comment: it's good to know that it is working perfect, but just for future reference,

use protected $casts = [
        'data' => 'array',
    ];

so you don't need to do json_encode or json_decode when you store or retrieve data from the database.